# Any detached/independent Session Library in PHP using Flat File or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, session, flat-file

Any detached/independent Session Library in PHP using Flat File or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using `Zend_Session` or any of [these PEAR packages](http://pear.php.net/search.php?q=session&in=packages&x=0&y=0) it is also pretty easy to write your own Session Handling. All you have to do is implement the required methods. See the example for [session_set_save_handler in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

As of PHP5.3 you could implement the callbacks with lambdas, so you don't have to clutter the global namespace with functions.

Answer (score 1):

[`Zend_Session`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.html) would probably do it. and [`Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html) there is also a save handler for flat file I believe.

Comment: I don't believe needs a lot of configuration, never used the saver handler but using `ZF` quiet a lot usually it is well documented and I believe you can easily find some blog/tutorial about this.